# Using jackson provider with cxf in osgi (no message body writer has been found)

Tags: java, osgi, jackson, cxf

I always get the errror: 
`Apr 09, 2014 2:03:19 AM org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.interceptor.JAXRSOutInterceptor writeResponseErrorMessage
WARNING: No message body writer has been found for response class Test.`

When trying to get a Test class to be parsed by jackson in a distributed osgi cxf environment.

Config in the web service:

```
restProps.put("service.exported.interfaces", "*");
restProps.put("service.exported.configs", "org.apache.cxf.rs");
restProps.put("service.exported.intents", "HTTP");
restProps.put("org.apache.cxf.rs.address", "http://localhost:8888/");
restProps.put("org.apache.cxf.rs.provider", "org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider");
context.registerService(Tester.class.getName(), new Tester(), restProps);
```

Config in the Tester class:

```
@Path("tester")
    public class Tester {
    @GET
    @Path("test")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Test testje(){
            return new Test("var");
    }
}
```

Test class definition:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "test")
public class Test {

    private String var;

    public Test(String var){
        this.var = var;
    }

}
```

In the manifest file I have included jackson:

```
Import-Package: org.codehaus.jackson;version="1.9.5"
```

Does someone see what might be the problem?

Comment: I'have the same problem!

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to test your service outside of osgi. if it works in jetty embedded with your test, it will work with jetty embedded in osgi. see these slides
http://www.slideshare.net/ielian/tdd-on-osgi

Second, you need JacksonJsonProvider to handle writing your objects to json and so the no message body writer

```
<jaxrs:server id="events" address="/events">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <ref bean="eventService"/>
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <bean class="org.codehaus.jackson.jaxrs.JacksonJsonProvider"/>
        <bean class="com.myexample.exception.WebExceptionHandler"/>
    </jaxrs:providers>
    <jaxrs:extensionMappings>
        <entry key="json" value="application/json"/>
    </jaxrs:extensionMappings>
</jaxrs:server>
```

Third, make sure your service produces application/json and your server address above is matched in the request for the provider mapping to take effect

```
@Override
@Produces({MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON})
@GET
public Collection<Event> getEvents ()
{
    return eventManager.getAllEvents();
}
```

Similarly on the client make sure you register a JacksonJsonProvider otherwise you will get a no message reader

```
    EventService eventService = JAXRSClientFactory.create(SERVICE_REST_URL, EventService.class, Collections.singletonList(new JacksonJsonProvider()));
```

I will load an example on github when I have time.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Use these dependencies -

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.9</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.8.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

Annotate your Controller with @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) and annotate your Model with @XmlRootElement.